# LDAP and ActiveDirectory authentication in C#

Tags: c#, ldap, userinfo

I am new to LDAP and active directory authentication , I just studied few things about LDAp authentication and done with sample application

I just checking Does the user exist in ActiveDirectory or not

```
public static bool DoesUserExist()
  {
  using (var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,Environment.UserDomainName))
   {
     using (var foundUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, Environment.UserName))
                {
                    return foundUser != null;
                }
            }
        }
```

in our local system its working fine , But when i hosted in ActiveDirectory Server and i am trying to access this with server IP address, i am facing some issue like

```
ContextType.Domain,Environment.UserDomainName and  Environment.UserName
```

for these three values are coming from server Information not the users who accessing this application

So please help me how to get the User information(who accessing this application) so that i need to pass those info to server and need check for user is activedirectory user or not

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET application?

Comment: Yes... ActiveDirectory authentication Using LDAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Environment.UserDomainName` returns the domain part of `Environment.UserName`, e.g. "mydomain.com", so you don't want that.

`Environment.UserName` itself will return the user who is currently "logged in to Windows", i.e. the app pool user - see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username(v=vs.110).aspx).

You are better off checking the identity of the current web request, so in a MVC Controller or WebForms Page, use `this.User`.

Or if you are using Windows Authentication or hooking Forms Authentication into AD, the current `Thread` `Principal` should be the current request user, so you can use [`Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: yes i tried using **Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name** but in local system its working fine, but i hosted on server, but still it returning server user name only not client UserName